# find a pattern in html and replace it with php code

Tags: php, python, bash, sed

I am looking at finding this pattern

```
<!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
   <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">

    <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
  </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

and replacing it with this pattern for a number of .html files

```
<!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
    <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
       <?php
            $year = date("Y");
            echo "<p class='text-muted'>© $year. Core Team</p>";
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the difference is that 
this

```
<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
```

is replaced with

```
       <?php
            $year = date("Y");
            echo "<p class='text-muted'>© $year. Core Team</p>";
        ?>
```

I was looking at doing it with `sed` but having had an initial attempt, my difficulty is the characters I might or might or might not have to escape. Also the tabs or new lines in the php code, I would like that to appear as is here.

There is a number of files to do it to so I would like to automate it but it might be quicker to just do it manually(copy and paste). But maybe `sed` is the wrong approach in this instance. Can someone kindly direct me in the right direction? At this stage I am open to other languages (e.g. php, python, bash ) to find a solution.

I would then plan to rename each .html file to .php with the following:

```
for i in *.html; do mv "$i" "${i%.*}.php"; done;
```

---

### EDIT1

bsed on the awk answer below I can get it to work under this version

```
$ awk -Wversion 2>/dev/null || awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 6.0.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2014 Free Software Foundation.
```

however on this version I get different output. It seems it prints out the 3 files, old new and file. **Is this easily rectified in this version?**

```
root@4461f768e343:/github/find_pattern# awk -Wversion 2>/dev/null || awk --version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

root@4461f768e343:/github/find_pattern#
root@4461f768e343:/github/find_pattern#
root@4461f768e343:/github/find_pattern# awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= 'ARGIND==1{old=$0;next} ARGIND==2{new=$0;next} s=index($0,old){ $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} 1' old new file
<!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
   <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">

    <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
  </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div><!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
    <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
       <?php
            $year = date("Y");
            echo "<p class='text-muted'>© $year. Core Team</p>";
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div>some pile of text
or other
<!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
   <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">

    <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
  </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div>
and more maybe.root@4461f768e343:/github/find_pattern#
```

Comment: I suggest to usa an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...) because [only Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace`.

```
html_files = ['a.html', ...]
copyright = '<p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>'
new_copyright = """       <?php
        $year = date("Y");
        echo "<p class='text-muted'>© $year. Core Team</p>";
    ?>"""
for html_file_path in html_files:
    with open(html_file_path) as html_file:
        html = html_file.read()

    if copyright in html:
        php_file_path = html_file_path.replace('.html', '.php')
        with open(php_file_path, "w") as php_file:
            php = html.replace(copyright, new_copyright)
            php_file.write(php)
```

Note this will not override your html files which is useful if the script has an error.

Comment: tried that but got this ```$ python find_pattern.py
  File "find_pattern.py", line 5
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file find_pattern.py on line 6, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details```

Comment: tks. had to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` this at the top of the file

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines so your task is certainly not a job for sed. You could use awk if your files are all that well formatted:

```
$ cat old
<!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
   <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">

    <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
  </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
$ cat new
<!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
    <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
       <?php
            $year = date("Y");
            echo "<p class='text-muted'>© $year. Core Team</p>";
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
$ cat file
some pile of text
or other
<!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
   <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">

    <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2014. Core Team</p>
  </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div>
and more maybe.
```

.

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= 'ARGIND==1{old=$0;next} ARGIND==2{new=$0;next} s=index($0,old){ $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} 1' old new file
some pile of text
or other
<!-- Footer part at bottom of page-->
<div id="footer">
    <div class="row col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
       <?php
            $year = date("Y");
            echo "<p class='text-muted'>© $year. Core Team</p>";
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="downloadlinks">
    <!-- downloadlinks go here-->
    </div>
</div>
and more maybe.
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and ARGIND. If you want to do it for many files you could use:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec awk -i inplace -v RS='^$' -v ORS= 'ARGIND==1{old=$0;print;next} ARGIND==2{new=$0;print;next} s=index($0,old){ $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} 1' old new {} \;
```

or similar.

Comment: that's a bit advanced awk for me, but tks currently looking in to this further for RS ORS and ARGIND [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web) and [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_117.html)

Comment: 1-for doing multiple files do I just need the `old` and `new` files?

Comment: 2-how sensitive is this, for instance does it allow for spaces slightly off or other slight differences?

Comment: 3-could you give a brief explaination of how this works?

Comment: can you see my edit1, I am getting different output with different version, is this easily fixed?

Comment: Yes but why bother since you have gawk? I added an example anyway.

Comment: have gawk on cygwin on my windows PC, but wanted to be able to do it in a container i have whcih has the diff version. which is painful for me with the diff versions but it is something  i would like to get a better handle on. advice welcome? And is gawk better?tks

Comment: Yes, gawk has far more useful extensions, is extremely well documented and supported, and has a large user base.

Comment: I can't get the example you added does not work(it seems to just pring the orig file). i've tried changing the parans.tks

Comment: Yeah, it'd need more work - you need to build up the record one line at a time for every file, not just the last one. Or you could pick come control character that you know won't be in the file for the RS instead of `^$` and stick closer to the gawk code, some people rely on `RS='\0'` but YMMV. I'll delete that example as I'm not interested in trying to make it work in non-gawk given it's not as simple as I first thought. If you try it and have any specific questions feel free to post a follow up and I'll try to help you.